# widfly 27 remote ejb lookup from external client app gives error : EJBCLIENT000409: No more destinations are available

Tags: java, client, ejb, wildfly, remote-access

Trying to look up a remote stateful EJB inside an EAR deployed on wildfly 27. I created a wildfly user for the `ApplicationRealm`.
I followed this tutorial:

https://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-as-7/jboss-as-7-remote-ejb-client-tutorial/

I'm aware that this is for jboss AS7 but I couldn't find anything more up to date.
A link to a current tutorial would as well help heaps.
I already reviewed other posts with the same error but no one seems to have a clue.
One even on the jboss.org site with no answer.

The application user was correctly added to
`application-users.properties`
in `standalone/configuration`.
I'm running wildfly with standalone-full config.

I'm getting these exceptions

```
INFO: JBoss EJB Client version 5.0.4.Final
javax.naming.CommunicationException: EJBCLIENT000062: Failed to look up "enterprise-y-ear/enterprise-y-ejb/TokenService!cs.edu.ey.ejb.remote.TokenServiceRemote?stateful"
[Root exception is org.jboss.ejb.client.RequestSendFailedException: EJBCLIENT000409: No more destinations are available]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBRootContext.lookupNative(EJBRootContext.java:160)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractContext.lookup(AbstractContext.java:84)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyRootContext.lookup(WildFlyRootContext.java:144)
at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
at cs.edu.enterprise.client.Main.lookupTokenServiceRemoteEJB(Main.java:55)
at cs.edu.enterprise.client.Main.main(Main.java:41)


Caused by: org.jboss.ejb.client.RequestSendFailedException: EJBCLIENT000409: No more destinations are available
at org.jboss.ejb.client.NamingEJBClientInterceptor.handleSessionCreation(NamingEJBClientInterceptor.java:125)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.proceed(EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.java:84)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.call(AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.java:59)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.handleSessionCreation(AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.java:39)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.proceed(EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.java:84)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleSessionCreation(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.proceed(EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.java:84)
at org.wildfly.common.context.Contextual.runExFunction(Contextual.java:287)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.proceedInitial(EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.java:47)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.createSession(EJBClientContext.java:900)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient.createSessionProxy(EJBClient.java:198)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBRootContext.lookupNative(EJBRootContext.java:158)
... 5 more
```

Lookup code

```
private static TokenServiceRemote lookupTokenServiceRemoteEJB() throws NamingException {
    final Hashtable<String, String> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<>();
    jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,  "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
            jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"http-remoting://localhost:8080");
    final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
    return (TokenServiceRemote) context
            .lookup("ejb:enterprise-y-ear/enterprise-y-ejb/TokenService!cs.edu.ey.ejb.remote.TokenServiceRemote?stateful");
}
```

Host and port are correct, I can call a servlet deployed in the same EAR via `http://localhost:8080`

When deploying the EAR the server log shows these JNDI names.

```
java:global/enterprise-y-ear/enterprise-y-ejb/TokenService!cs.edu.ey.ejb.local.TokenServiceLocal
java:app/enterprise-y-ejb/TokenService!cs.edu.ey.ejb.local.TokenServiceLocal
java:module/TokenService!cs.edu.ey.ejb.local.TokenServiceLocal
java:global/enterprise-y-ear/enterprise-y-ejb/TokenService!cs.edu.ey.ejb.remote.TokenServiceRemote
java:app/enterprise-y-ejb/TokenService!cs.edu.ey.ejb.remote.TokenServiceRemote
java:module/TokenService!cs.edu.ey.ejb.remote.TokenServiceRemote
java:jboss/exported/enterprise-y-ear/enterprise-y-ejb/TokenService!cs.edu.ey.ejb.remote.TokenServiceRemote
ejb:enterprise-y-ear/enterprise-y-ejb/TokenService!cs.edu.ey.ejb.remote.TokenServiceRemote?stateful
```

Maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools-builder</artifactId>
    <version>26.1.3.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
    <version>28.0.1.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

wildfly-config.xml

```
<configuration>
    <authentication-client xmlns="urn:elytron:1.0">
        <authentication-rules>
            <rule use-configuration="default"/>
        </authentication-rules>
        <authentication-configurations>
            <configuration name="default">
                <sasl-mechanism-selector selector="DIGEST-MD5"/>
                <set-user-name name="*****"/>
                <credentials>
                    <clear-password password="*****"/>
                </credentials>
            </configuration>
        </authentication-configurations>
    </authentication-client>    
</configuration>
```

I tried the second option mentonened in the tutorial as well, using http transport.
I added the following two dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.wildfly-http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-http-client-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-naming-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And changed the url to following.
`jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"http://localhost:8080/wildfly-services`

Now I'm getting an authentication error.

```
Juni 24, 2023 7:54:34 AM org.wildfly.httpclient.common.HttpTargetContext lambda$acquireSessionAffinity$1
ERROR: WFHTTP000003: Failed to acquire session
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: WFHTTP000013: Authentication failed (full response ClientResponse{responseHeaders={www-authenticate=[Basic realm="ApplicationRealm"], 
set-cookie=[JSESSIONID=Fkxcqh8cki41m1gUD4FoIu5TKXFyljEZoqi9V1cB.laptop-s32qmbmt; path=/wildfly-services], content-length=[77], 
content-type=[text/html], date=[Sat, 24 Jun 2023 05:54:34 GMT]}, responseCode=401, status='', protocol=HTTP/2.0})
at org.wildfly.httpclient.common.HttpTargetContext$2$1.lambda$completed$4(HttpTargetContext.java:243)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Juni 24, 2023 7:54:34 AM org.wildfly.httpclient.common.HttpTargetContext lambda$acquireSessionAffinity$1
ERROR: WFHTTP000003: Failed to acquire session
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at io.undertow.client.http2.Http2ClientConnection.close(Http2ClientConnection.java:308)
at io.undertow.client.http.HttpClientConnection.close(HttpClientConnection.java:485)
at org.xnio.IoUtils.safeClose(IoUtils.java:152)
at org.wildfly.httpclient.common.HttpConnectionPool$ClientConnectionHolder.done(HttpConnectionPool.java:302)
at org.wildfly.httpclient.common.HttpTargetContext$2$1.lambda$completed$4(HttpTargetContext.java:250)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

javax.naming.CommunicationException: EJBCLIENT000062: Failed to look up "enterprise-y-ear/enterprise-y-ejb/TokenService!cs.edu.ey.ejb.remote.TokenServiceRemote?stateful" [Root exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: WFHTTP000013: Authentication failed (full response ClientResponse{responseHeaders={www-authenticate=[Basic realm="ApplicationRealm"], set-cookie=[JSESSIONID=oUUFFYzj09w2stNm21YtoJDh8t4Yrg9K9Ee6Qjh6.laptop-s32qmbmt; path=/wildfly-services], content-length=[77], content-type=[text/html], date=[Sat, 24 Jun 2023 05:54:34 GMT]}, responseCode=401, status='', protocol=HTTP/2.0})]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBRootContext.lookupNative(EJBRootContext.java:160)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractContext.lookup(AbstractContext.java:84)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyRootContext.lookup(WildFlyRootContext.java:144)
at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
at cs.edu.enterprise.client.Main.lookupTokenServiceRemoteEJB(Main.java:56)
at cs.edu.enterprise.client.Main.main(Main.java:41)

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: WFHTTP000013: Authentication failed (full response ClientResponse{responseHeaders={www-authenticate=[Basic realm="ApplicationRealm"], set-cookie=[JSESSIONID=oUUFFYzj09w2stNm21YtoJDh8t4Yrg9K9Ee6Qjh6.laptop-s32qmbmt; path=/wildfly-services], content-length=[77], content-type=[text/html], date=[Sat, 24 Jun 2023 05:54:34 GMT]}, responseCode=401, status='', protocol=HTTP/2.0})
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:396)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
at org.wildfly.httpclient.ejb.HttpEJBReceiver.createSession(HttpEJBReceiver.java:314)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.proceed(EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.java:74)
at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.handleSessionCreation(RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.proceed(EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.java:84)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.handleSessionCreation(TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.java:108)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.proceed(EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.java:84)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.handleSessionCreation(DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.java:171)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.proceed(EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.java:84)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.NamingEJBClientInterceptor.handleSessionCreation(NamingEJBClientInterceptor.java:107)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.proceed(EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.java:84)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.call(AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.java:59)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.handleSessionCreation(AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.java:39)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.proceed(EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.java:84)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleSessionCreation(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.proceed(EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.java:84)
at org.wildfly.common.context.Contextual.runExFunction(Contextual.java:287)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.proceedInitial(EJBSessionCreationInvocationContext.java:47)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.createSession(EJBClientContext.java:900)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient.createSessionProxy(EJBClient.java:198)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBRootContext.lookupNative(EJBRootContext.java:158)
... 5 more

 Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: WFHTTP000013: Authentication failed (full response ClientResponse{responseHeaders={www-authenticate=[Basic realm="ApplicationRealm"], set-cookie=[JSESSIONID=oUUFFYzj09w2stNm21YtoJDh8t4Yrg9K9Ee6Qjh6.laptop-s32qmbmt; path=/wildfly-services], content-length=[77], content-type=[text/html], date=[Sat, 24 Jun 2023 05:54:34 GMT]}, responseCode=401, status='', protocol=HTTP/2.0})
at org.wildfly.httpclient.common.HttpTargetContext$2$1.lambda$completed$4(HttpTargetContext.java:243)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved with the help of these tutorials:

https://github.com/wildfly-security-incubator/elytron-examples/tree/main/ejb-http

https://wildfly-security.github.io/wildfly-elytron/blog/ejb-over-http/

The issue lied within the details of the wildfly configuration.
I was missing some of the settings and my wildfly conifg was imcomplete. The following is what worked.

server config:

```
/subsystem=elytron/filesystem-realm=fsRealm:add(path=fs-realm-users, relative-to=jboss.server.config.dir)

/subsystem=elytron/filesystem-realm=fsRealm:add-identity(identity=quickstartUser)
/subsystem=elytron/filesystem-realm=fsRealm:set-password(clear={password=quickstartPwd1!},identity=quickstartUser)
/subsystem=elytron/filesystem-realm=fsRealm:add-identity-attribute(identity=quickstartUser, name=Roles, value=[guest])

/subsystem=elytron/simple-role-decoder=from-roles-attribute:add(attribute=Roles)

/subsystem=elytron/security-domain=fsSD:add(realms=[{realm=fsRealm, role-decoder=from-roles-attribute}], default-realm=fsRealm,permission-mapper=default-permission-mapper)

/subsystem=ejb3/application-security-domain=other:add(security-domain=fsSD)
```

http-transport:

```
/subsystem=elytron/http-authentication-factory=example-http-auth:add(http-server-mechanism-factory=global,security-domain=fsSD,mechanism-configurations=[{mechanism-name=BASIC,mechanism-realm-configurations=[{realm-name=fsRealm}]}])

/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/setting=http-invoker:undefine-attribute(name=security-realm)

/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/setting=http-invoker:write-attribute(name=http-authentication-factory, value=example-http-auth)
```

client key store:

```
WILDFLY_HOME/bin/elytron-tool.bat credential-store --create --location "/PATH/TO/mycredstore.cs" --password StorePassword

WILDFLY_HOME/bin/elytron-tool.bat credential-store --location "/PATH/TO/mycredstore.cs" --password StorePassword --add quickstartUser --secret quickstartPwd1!
```

wildfly-config.xml (in resources folder)
the path to the client key store would then be:

src/main/resources/mycredstore.cs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <authentication-client xmlns="urn:elytron:client:1.7">
        <credential-stores>
            <credential-store name="mycredstore">
                <attributes>
                    <attribute name="keyStoreType" value="JCEKS"/>
                    <attribute name="location" value="/PATH/TO/mycredstore.cs"></attribute>
                </attributes>
                <protection-parameter-credentials>
                    <clear-password password="StorePassword"/>
                </protection-parameter-credentials>
            </credential-store>
        </credential-stores>

        <authentication-rules>
            <rule use-configuration="default-config"/>
        </authentication-rules>
        <authentication-configurations>
            <configuration name="default-config">
                <set-user-name name="quickstartUser"/>
                <credentials>
                    <credential-store-reference store="mycredstore" alias="quickstartUser"/>
                </credentials>
                <providers>
                    <use-service-loader />
                </providers>
            </configuration>
        </authentication-configurations>
    </authentication-client>
</configuration>
```

the actual lookup

```
private static TokenServiceRemote lookup() throws NamingException {
    final Hashtable<String, String> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<>();
    jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http://localhost:8080/wildfly-services");
    final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
    return (TokenServiceRemote) context.lookup("ejb:enterprise-y-ear/enterprise-y-ejb/TokenService!cs.edu.ey.ejb.remote.TokenServiceRemote?stateful");
}
```